# Reverse ring sizes

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, macro-converter

I recently ordered a reverse ring and turn out i ordered a wrong one. My camera is 7100 but i ordered D700 from [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/131337885099?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT), i bet it won't be exchange but can i order something else to put it on my lens, so it make use for reverse ring 72mm for D700 use for my D7100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reversing ring such as the BR2A ([Nikon](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Miscellaneous/2657/BR-2A-Lens-Reversing-Ring-for-52mm-Thread.html), [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/37171-REG/Nikon_2657_BR_2A_Lens_Reversing_Ring.html)) have a Nikon F mount on one side and a thread that matches the front of a camera lens on the other.

Nikon doesn't make any 72mm or 67mm reverse rings though you can find it from third parties ([72mm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054ENYEG) for example).

I will point out that lenses that use a 72mm (or 67mm) thread are not likely good candidates for using as a reversed lens.  These are likely either zoom lenses or very wide. They are not likely designed to take the weight of the lens on the filter thread.

You would likely be much better off with the BR2A from above and a Nikon 50mm f/1.8D lens. The D is important because it still has the f/stop ring and so you can manually stop down the lens. With lenses that don't have the f/stop ring (G lenses) you will find that you cannot change the f/stop on the lens after you have removed it from the camera.

Comment: So I bought the wrong reverse ring?

Comment: @Nofel If your lens doesn't use a 72mm thread, you bought the wrong reverse ring. I personally would be rather hesitant to use a lens that takes a 72mm thread (or 67mm) reversed because of the stresses placed on the filter ring with a heavier lens the filter size implies.

Comment: So now i bough wrong one, should i buy a size down ring to mount the reserve ring?

Comment: @Nofel what lens are you trying to reverse mount?

Comment: @MichealT I have 18-105 lens and reverse ring of 72mm

Comment: I'm going to say that I *really* don't believe that that is a useful lens to reverse mount. That its a G rather than D lens means you can't control the fstop.  The lens is 15 oz and isn't designed to be hung off its threads.  You could get the 72-67 step *up* ring, but again I don't think that you'll be getting what you expect. I really think you'd find yourself better off with a [50mm f/1.8D](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/247091-USA/) and a [BR-2A](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/37171-REG/). Yes, its more expensive than a reversing ring - it will give you better results.

Comment: @MichealT yea, your right but buying a 50mm will be redundant as i already have 18-105mm and it got 50mm in it? Plus i don't know about D/G or F mounts thing.

Comment: @Nofel you have a 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6.  At 50mm, its about an f/4.  The 50mm f/1.8 will let in about 10x more light. This means when you're looking at taking a shot at 1/6th of a second with the zoom, you can handhold it at 1/60th with the 50mm f/1.8. This also gives you a shallower depth of field (useful for portraiture). I've got from 17-400 covered in zooms (17-35, 24-70, 80-400). I also carry a some combination of 35mm, 50mm, 85mm, 105mm and 135mm depending on what I want to do (the 105mm is a macro lens). Primes and zooms have different utility - they aren't redundant.

Comment: @MicaelT thanks, So how can i make use of my 72mm reverse ring? I don't want to waste it. any suggestion?

Comment: @Nofel you may find yourself with a 72mm threaded lens. That said, I am still concerned about hanging that much glass off the filter thread ring. Those threads aren't intended to take much weight. Chalk it up to a learning experience. Throughout the course of your photography you will find you have many of them (I had a 17-40mm sigma that turned out to have awful aberrations... and an 82mm thread filter... and filters at that size aren't cheap and if they are, they're *really* cheaply made).

Answer (score 0):

Your camera model doesn't matter. All you need is a Nikon mount reverse ring with the correct size filter threads.

What size is the filter thread on your lens?

Comment: The nikon site says 67mm thread.

Comment: Please don't use answers to request additional information, use comments for that.